# How to get basic ipywidgets text box working properly in JupyterLab 3.2.9?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, ipywidgets

I'm playing with the Reddit API and I'd like to have a basic text box for the user to input a subreddit to search. I want this interactivity so that I can (hopefully) post my notebook on github or nbviewer and have someone else try it. When I try to run my code, several things happen:

1. The notebook continues to execute code cells instead of waiting for user to input a subreddit
2. If I execute the cells manually, I can get the text box to appear, but then nothing happens when I hit 'Enter'.

Below is my code:

```
def onchange(change):
    with caption:
        print(change.value)
        
sub = widgets.Text(placeholder='Enter subreddit', description='r/')
caption = widgets.Output()

display(sub)
sub.on_submit(onchange)
```

And here is what it looks like when I execute the cell manually:

[image: My cell output]

Answer (score 1):

You need to `display(output)` after your `display(sub)` initially, and go from there.

The `output` widget is capturing the output of the Text widget, so you need to `display` that `output` widget too.

You might be able to make a simpler implementation using the `interactive` options with ipywidgets, but I prefer the more explicit version using `observe` and `on_click` etc.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a shot soon and see what happens. For my notebook, I'd just want the user to type in their string, and hit "Enter" and then continue on with the notebook. I'm currently using the built-in `string = input()` way, since it does what I want locally. Would the interactive method be better suited for that?

Comment: Hard to say without knowing what behaviour you want, but you can't run extra cells of your notebook using the text widget if that is what you had in mind. Probably best to add another q like you did here if you can't get things to work the way you want.